# If there's a submodule homomorphism to a quotient space is it a quotient module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $M$ be $Z$-module.   Suppose we've made an identification on $M$ and created a quotient space $M^*$ (i.e. it's partitioned by an equivalence relation).  Suppose that there's a module structure on $M^*$ and a homomorphism of $M$ onto $M^*$.  Then is $M^*$ a quotient module $M/N$ for some submodule $N$?  Thanks.

Comment: I guess the kernel is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first isomorphism theorem. If you have a homomorphism $\varphi:M\to M^\ast$, and if $N=\ker\varphi$ then the induced map $M/N\to M^\ast$ is an isomorphism.